# iPad leak - NSPushAutoreleasePool

Tags: iphone

We are getting a sizable leak (16kb) that is proving very difficult to eliminate.  The responsible library is Foundation and the Responsible frame is NSPushAutoreleasePool.  This leak does not appear on the iPhone, only the iPad.  We get the following stack trace:

```
   9 libSystem.B.dylib thread_assign_default
   8 libSystem.B.dylib _pthread_start
   7 WebCore RunWebThread(void*)
   6 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunInMode
   5 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific
   4 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoObservers
   3 WebCore WebRunLoopLock(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
   2 Foundation NSPushAutoreleasePool
   1 Foundation _NSAPAddPage
   0 libSystem.B.dylib malloc
```

We're getting a similar one in the frame NSAutoReleasePool. We've checked everywhere in the code we create an autoreleasepool to make sure we're releasing it.

Since none of this is our code I'm not sure how to proceed.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you explicitly draining the pools you create or just releasing them?

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: We have tried calling the drain method but it doesn't plug the leak.